# USB adapters don't work on some USB ports

Tags: 20.04, usb, bluetooth

On my laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 I have 3 usb ports: 2 x 3.0 + 1 x 2.0
Only one of 3.0 ports recognises  USB adapters (bluetooth and Logitech receiver), but another doesn't. At the same time the second 3.0 port does recognise USB drives.
The 2.0 port doesn't recognise anything.

here's the output of lsusb

First port is Logitech Receiver, second is assus bluetooth (doesn't appear in the output)

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Vice versa

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0b05:190e ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ASUS USB-BT500
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Let's forget about 2.0 port (unless it matters),
Why only 1 3.0 port works with adapters?

Updated:
Kernel version is 5.13.0-27-generic
Laptop model is Asus K550L

Comment: A little information about your system will be required to answer this question. Could you [edit] the post to include: (0) the kernel version you're running (1) the brand/model of your computer (or motherboard if it's a desktop). With this, it will be possible to investigate driver compatibility issues.